# Child element hiding sibling

Tags: html, css, user-interface, drop-down-menu

[image]
I would like to see my menu links.

I have implemented a CSS dropdown menu using the checkbox hack.

I have attached an icon to the bottom of the menu. When triggered, the menu drags the icon down along with it.

However, the icon's "margin" (according to dev tools) covers the entire width of the menu, such that the only way to display the links in the menu is to make the menu drop down significantly lower, changing:

```
#navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu ul {
        max-height: 50px; ==============> 75px
        z-index: 3;
}
```

I have tried just about everything I can think of: from `z-index`, to all kinds of `position`s, to `transparent` to `opacity` etc.

I simply want to display the links.

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
}
.menu {
  padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
  background: transparent;
  min-height: 2.75em;
  line-height: 0em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  color: white;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
#logo {
  background-image: url("http://www.rocstarr.com/Tipapalooza/files/tipapalooza-icon-100x100.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
}
.logo:hover {
  color: mediumturquoise;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.menu .logo div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.logo p {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: 'Coustard', serif;
}
.menu ul {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  transition: max-height 0.4s linear 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.menu a:hover {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .45em 1.1em;
}
@media(max-width:321px){

#logo {
  margin-left: 5%;
}
}
@media (min-width: 0px) {
  .menu ul {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .menu li {
    visibility: visible;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4em 0 0.5em;
    border: none;
    margin-right: 4px;
  }
  .menu .navbar-handle {
    display: block;
  }
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu ul {
    max-height: 50px;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu li {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu .navbar-handle,
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu .navbar-handle:after,
  #navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu .navbar-handle:before {
    border-color: white;
  }
}
.navbar-handle {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: .5em 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 1.6666666666666667em;
  border-top: 0.13333333333333333em solid;
}
.navbar-handle:before,
.navbar-handle:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: ' ';
  border-top: 0.13333333333333333em solid;
}
.navbar-handle:before {
  top: 0.37777777777777777em;
}
.navbar-handle:after {
  top: 0.8888888888888888em;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.menu .navbar-handle {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  top: 1.3em;
  color: white;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.navbar-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-checkbox">
<nav class="menu">
  <a class="logo" href="http://myapp.com">
    <div class="logo">
      <p>myapp.com</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">how it works</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">about us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p id="logo"></p>
  <label for="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-handle"></label>
</nav>
```

Comment: tell me in short what you want? i did not understant your question

Comment: @reenlendr to see the menu links. Run the code snippet you will understand

Comment: okey i got it.. wait ..

Answer (score 0):

here are corrections:

put these before

```
<p id="logo"></p>
<label for="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-handle"></label>
<ul></ul>
```

these style must be added and edited

```
#logo {float: left;}
#navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu ul {
max-height: 75px;}
```

My advice:

```
#navbar-checkbox:checked + .menu ul {
display: block;
}

#navbar-checkbox + .menu ul {
display: none;
}
```

Do not use height as parameter.

Comment: brother you will have to redesign your page.. and use display as parameter not height.. it will work.. i used it in my recent project

Comment: you will have to add more properties in this class

Comment: Does the code you posted work with my code? Or are you suggesting I rewrite? @reenleedr

Comment: but if you dont want to rewrite.. the put <label> before <ul>. and remove padding of <li>

Comment: I'd rewrite it if I wasn't curious why it's not working. Why are they even being hidden in the first place? @reenleedr

Comment: because overflow is hidden... and the are visible at height: 75px

Comment: Please do. Im still trying to figure it out

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the icon was intentionally placed on the bottom of the menu. I want it to drop down with the line. However now, neither the line nor the icon drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to see the links visible just try to adjust the padding of .menu li padding: 4em 0 0.6em; to padding: 2em 0 0.6em;

Comment: I thought your first priority is to make the links visible. Do you want to move the links?

Comment: My first priority is to make the links visible. Moving them is not a solution it is an alternative.

Comment: I think the links are visible now by changing the value of padding to .menu li.

Comment: No when you change the value of padding you move the links

Comment: For moving the links try to add width to .menu ul as 90%.